# Vue js seems to break bootstrap pagination

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I am trying to paginate views in vueJS and I have my pagination markup like so:

```html
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link"  v-if="page != 1" @click="page--">
        Previous
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" v-for="pageNumber in pages.slice(page-1, page+5)" @click="page = pageNumber">
        [[pageNumber]]
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" @click="page++" v-if="page < pages.length">
        Next
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

While the pagination code is all good, the pagination somehow alligns vertically rather than horizontally like so:

[image]

I note that it is this code which seems to be breaking it:

```html
<li class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" v-for="pageNumber in pages.slice(page-1, page+5)" @click="page = pageNumber">
    [[pageNumber]]
  </a>
</li>
```

Would anyone know why this happens? I am no front end dev and my HTML skills arent the best either - any pointers would be great.

thank you.

Comment: You probably needs to add css rule `display: inline-block;` to your `.page-item` class. Note: Adding `css` styling rules will help to help ;-) Can you add them? Or at the best reproduce this in codepen.io?

Comment: after this line " <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" @click="page++" v-if="page < pages.length">Next</a></li>" there is a </div> without opening i think that is causing the problem

Comment: @pinoyCoder: hmm no I took that typo off and it still behaves the same.. :(

Comment: @AdamOrlov: hmm, no dice with that css rule :(

Comment: @JohnM then reproduce the problem on codepen.io or codesandbox, or at least show us your `css` code. We don't know what is inside classes `page-item` or `page-link`.

Comment: are you putting this component on a parent container? or better yet show us how are you using this component.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your pagination is looking all wrong is because you're placing the `v-for` on your `a` tag in side the `li`.

You need to instead place it on the `li` as each `li` represents a page button

In the snippet I've replaced your `v-if` on the next button as it might be confusing to have the buttton disappear.
Instead I've used a conditional class.

As an alternative you could utilize[bootstrap-vue's pagination](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination) which might save your some trouble of writing the logic yourself.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      page: 1,
      pages: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item" :class="{ 'disabled': page == pages[0] }">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page--">
            Previous
          </a>
        </li>
      <li class="page-item" 
          :class="{ 'active': page === pageNumber }" 
          v-for="pageNumber in pages.slice(page-1, page+4)">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page = pageNumber">
          {{ pageNumber }}
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="page-item" :class="{ 'disabled': page >= pages.length }">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page++">
          Next
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```